# Trying to build quiz format in Django, questions are listing properly but not able to get the options listed

Tags: python, django

Hi i am quite new to django and python was trying to build some quiz pattern
i am not able to map options to questions and list them.

**models.py**

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.

    class Date_list(models.Model):
        date_gk = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        CA_BGimage = models.CharField(max_length=20)


        def __str__(self):
         return 'Daily Current Affair and GK quiz: ' + self.date_gk


    class Questions(models.Model):
        date_list = models.ForeignKey(Date_list, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
        question = models.CharField(max_length=500)

        def __str__(self):
         return self.question

    class Options(models.Model):
        questions = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
        option = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        correct_answer =models.CharField(max_length=100)


        def __str__(self):
         return self.option
```

**views.py**

```
        from django.shortcuts import render
        from django.http import HttpResponse
        from .models import Date_list, Questions
        from django.template import loader
        from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
        # Create your views here.


        def index(request):
            all_dates = Date_list.objects.all()
            context = {'all_dates': all_dates,}
            return render(request, 'Current_Affair/index.html', context)

        def detail(request, date_list_id, questions_id):
            date_list = get_object_or_404(Date_list, pk=date_list_id)
            questions = get_object_or_404(Questions, pk=questions_id)
            return render(request, 'Current_Affair/detail.html', {'date_list':date_list}, {'questions':questions})
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    app_name = 'Current_Affair'

    urlpatterns = [
            #Current_Affair
            url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),


            #/Current_Affair/32
        url(r'^(?P<date_list_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    ]
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Loads the path to your static files -->
{% load staticfiles %}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Current_Affair/style.css' %}" />




<h1> <strong> Daily Current Affairs & GK Quiz </strong></h1>
<ul>
    {% for datess in all_dates %}
    <li><a href="/Current_Affair/{{ datess.id }}">{{ datess.date_gk }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

detail.html

```
<h1> QUIZ </h1>
{% for q in date_list.questions_set.all %}
    <div> {{ q.question }} </div>
    {% for o in questions.options_set.all %}
          {{ o.option }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


style.css

body {
    background-image: url("images/b2.jpeg");
}
```

I am getting below error .
Can anyone plz help ...Thanks

> TypeError at /Current_Affair/1/ detail() takes exactly 3 arguments (2
>   given) Request Method:    GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/Current_Affair/1/ Django Version: 1.9
>   Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   detail() takes exactly 3
>   arguments (2 given) Exception
>   Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py
>   in get_response, line 147 Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
>   Python Version:   2.7.13 Python Path: 
>   ['C:\Users\vijay\Desktop\Knowledge_Basket', 
>   'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python27.zip',  'C:\Python27\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Python27\lib',  'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win', 
>   'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',  'C:\Python27', 
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages', 
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py2.7.egg'] Server
>   time: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 20:51:54 +0530

Answer (score 0):

In your url:

```
 url(r'^(?P<date_list_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

You define only 1 parameter `date_list_id`

You got to add `questions_id` in your urls.py=>

```
 url(r'^(?P<date_list_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<questions_id>[0-9]+)$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

And in your template =>

```
  <li><a href="/Current_Affair/{{ datess.id }}/{{ question.id }}">{{ datess.date_gk }}</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying ...but it not working i  ... i have updated the files     as below ......detail.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying ...but it not working i  ... i have updated the files     as below ......detail.html        <h1> QUIZ </h1>
{% for q in date_list.questions_set.all %}
 <div> {{ q.question }} </div>
 {% for o in questions.options_set.all %}
 <li><a href="/Current_Affair/{{ datess.id }}/{{ question.id }}">{{ o.option }}</a></li>
    
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: and  urls.py as from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'Current_Affair'

urlpatterns = [
  #Current_Affair
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
  
  
  #/Current_Affair/32
 #url(r'^(?P<date_list_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
 url(r'^(?P<date_list_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<questions_id>[0-9]+)$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
   i am getting the below error  404 error

Comment: error :: Using the URLconf defined in Knowledge_Basket.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^Current_Affair/ ^$ [name='index']
^Current_Affair/ ^(?P<date_list_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<questions_id>[0-9]+)$ [name='detail']
The current URL, Current_Affair/1/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: The format which i want is something like .. In homepage user gets the dates  ... once he selects the date he goes to a page and there he gets list of all questions of that date along with options in same page

Comment: Just to give the idea of flow 
home page

Date 1 
Date 2

User selected date1 

see's the below page 


QUIZ 



 < question  1>
 
 Option 1
 option 2 
 option 3
 
 
 
 < question 2>
 
 Option 1
 option 2 
 option 3
 
 
 
 < question 3>
 
 Option 1
 option 2 
 option 3